# Proper asynchronous stochastic gradient descent with celery

Tags: python, celery, distributed, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

I have to use celery to parallelize a stochastic gradient descent algorithm, though that might not be the better choice to do it with celery, this is still my question =)

The algorithm looks like that, where datas is the matrix of samples:

```
#Random init of the minimum:
x_current = np.random.random(n_dim)    

for i in range(max_iter):
    #Randomizes the lines, i.e. the samples of the minibatches at each iteration
    np.random.shuffle(datas)

    #I update my gradient by minibatches of n samples
    for batch in range(datas.shape[0] / n)

        delta = gradient(x_current, datas[(batch*n):(batch*(n+1)),:])
        x_current += delta
```

gradient is the function to be distributed as a task. Let's say I have 10 workers, at first, I create 10 tasks gradient with the 10 first minibatches.

When someone finishes, I want a new task to be created with the next minibatch (it doesn't matter if it changes of iteration and go back to the first minibatch) and the current version of x_current (it doesn't matter if it's not the very last version).

Also, I have to get the result and update x_current with the delta returned. All deltas have to be applied "sequentially" on x_current (but the order doesn't matter), and asynchronously with the tasks creation.

My question is, what is the most elegant way of doing it with celery?
Thank you :)